# SQL Server xp_cmdshell returns access denied

Tags: sql-server

I create a stored procedure to use command line to execute an application, and I have configured `xp_cmdshell` to 1, but still I get an error "Access is denied".

Here is the script for the stored procedure:

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[CASS]
As
Begin
    Declare @Command Varchar(255)

    Set @Command = '\\irsrvapp1\BCC\MM2010\MailMan.exe -j "SEQUEL TEST.mjb" 
                   -u "LARRY" -w "1234"';
    Exec xp_cmdshell @Command
End
```

Comment: please post exact error messages

Answer (score 0):

there are two security settings for your command.

1) SQL Server permissions to execute xp_cmdshell:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql

2) Permissions for the network resource (\irsrvapp1\BCC\MM2010)

Comment: Hello Anton, right now, I am using internal net, so i think i can access to network resource directly and I have opened xp_cmdshell permission.

Comment: it's likely the problem is with (2), you can check it easily if you execute some local command. What account to you use to run xp_cmdshell and what's your permissions for the network resource?

Comment: yes, I just give it a shot, it can run local commands but cannot execute this one. i am the sys admin and i think i also have full permission for network resources.

Comment: sorry, I meant not your permissions, but permission of an account which executes xp_cmdshell